# Win 8.1 “Metro” VPN: How to create with “Allow other people to use this connection” enabled?

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1, there appear to be 2 ways to create a VPN connection.  One way is through the 'Metro' interface, PC Settings > Network > Add VPN Connection.  The second way is the 'Windows 7' way, Control Panel > Network And Sharing Center > Set up a new connection or network > Connect to a workplace > Create a new connection > Use my Internet connection (VPN).

In the 'Metro' wizard, there is a drop down to select a specific type of VPN provider (screenshot below). Selecting the type of VPN is not in the 'Windows 7' wizard.

In the 'Windows 7' wizard, there is a check box that says 'Allow other people to use this connection', but I cannot find an equivalent option for a VPN created through the 'Metro' interface.  Where is this 'Allow other people to use this connection' setting stored?

My end goal is to have a connection for a specific VPN provider that is available to all users of the PC.

Thanks

Screenshot showing the specific VPN providers included in Windows 8.1:

[image: screen shot showing the specific VPN providers in Win 8.1]

Comment: Juniper is Juniper Networks - nothing to do with Windows 8.1 "built-in". I'm unsure if the Juniper client can do connections for all users...

Comment: I updated the question to generalize it.  Although I am specifically working with the Juniper provider, the problem exists for all VPN providers built-in to Win 8.1.

Comment: This simply creates an SSTP connection for me. You sure there’s some actual “magic” involved?

Comment: According to a MS forum the only way to create a VPN connection using the Windows "built-in" VPN client that supports allowing other users to connect using the connection you create is through the wizard that you've already detailed. The forum says that if you need to change a VPN to allow other users to connect you need to recreatethe VPN but tick to allow other users.

Comment: When you create a VPN connection in Windows it creates an IKEv2 connection with automatic VPN type. I've seen this in both 7 and 8...

Comment: @BigChris - What the forum says is exactly the problem I am trying to address, there is no check box for 'allow other users' in the 'built-in' VPN client creation screen.

Comment: @DanielB - I tried creating an SSTP connection (Win7 wizard) but it gave an error and wouldn't connect.  So I have one SSTP connection created with the 'Metro' wizard that connects and one SSTP connection created with the 'Win7' wizard that fails to connect.  I have gone over each value in the properties dialog and they are exactly the same.  There must be some magic somewhere.

Comment: The option likely isn't offered for some technical reason.  I suggest using the desktop method until the Metro method is updated in the future by Microsoft.  You can also share the VPN connection using some [other method](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7).